# Метод audio.get не возвращает данные (VK API)

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Создал Standalone-приложение, получаю токен через браузер

```
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=#######&display=page&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&scope=friends,wall,photos,groups,audio&response_type=token&v=5.60&state=123456
```

Отправляю запрос

```
https://api.vk.com/method/audio.get?user_id=#########&need_user=0&count=1000&offset=0&access_token=" + token + "&v=5.62
```

Получаю ответ

```
{u'response': {u'count': 1,
               u'items': [{u'artist': u'\u0410\u0443\u0434\u0438\u043e \u0434\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0443\u043f\u043d\u043e \u043d\u0430 vk.com',
                           u'date': 1481906888,
                           u'duration': 25,
                           u'id': 1,
                           u'owner_id': 100,
                           u'title': u'\u0438 \u0432 \u043e\u0444\u0438\u0446\u0438\u0430\u043b\u044c\u043d\u044b\u0445 \u043f\u0440\u0438\u043b\u043e\u0436\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f\u0445 \u0412\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0442\u0430\u043a\u0442\u0435',
                           u'url': u'https://vk.com/mp3/audio_api_unavailable.mp3'}]}}
```

Спасибо.

Comment: В запросе дя указания пользователя также использовал "owner_id" и "oid", ответ остался неизменным.

Comment: Вы хотите знать как `u'\u0410..'` строку в `"Аудио доступно на vk.com и в официальных приложениях ВКонтакте"` преобразовать или сама фраза не ясна?

Comment: не помещайте информацию необходимую для ответа в комментарии, отредактируйте ваш вопрос вместо этого.

Comment: Спасибо за реакцию. Я рассчитывал получить список аудиозаписей этого пользователя с возможностью закачать пакетно.

Comment: Насколько я понял фразу: это API доступно только для "официальных приложений ВКонтакте" (фиксированный список client_id) или если сервер думает, что вы не бот, а человек, который в браузере на vk.com зашёл (я не знаю насколько это действительности соответствует).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://vk.com/dev/audio_api

> С 16 декабря 2016 года мы отключаем публичный API для работы с аудиозаписями. Существующие методы секции audio будут недоступны для вызова, кроме методов для загрузки аудиофайлов.
>
> Если в Вашем приложении используются методы для работы с аудио, необходимо отключить связанную с ними логику. Сервер API будет возвращать сообщение об ошибке в ответ на такие запросы.
>
> Мы понимаем, что в результате Ваше приложение может полностью перестать работать или лишиться значительной части своих возможностей. И в абсолютном большинстве случаев мы не сможем предложить альтернативу.

Answer (score 0):

Аудио можно парсить так:

```
import bot_vk #pip install bot_vk==1.7
info1 = bot_vk.audio.get(owner_id=1234567)
```

оригинал: https://habr.com/post/429942